# QueryDsl to produce a native query

Tags: querydsl

Is there any way to convert querydsl query to native query including query parameters? Currently i have something like

```
    QDrm qdrm = QDrm.drm;

    String table = "drm";
    Path<Object> userPath = new PathImpl<Object>(Object.class, table);
    StringPath usernamePath = Expressions.stringPath(userPath, "accessory_id");
    query.from(qdrm).where(qdrm.accessory_id.eq(100l));
    query.where(qdrm.time.lt("2104-04-14"));

    System.out.println(query.getSQL(usernamePath).getSQL());
```

This results in following output :

```
select drm.accessory_id
from drm
where drm.accessory_id = ? and drm.time < ?
```

My goal is to produce

```
select drm.accessory_id
from drm
where drm.accessory_id = 100 and drm.time < "2104-04-14"
```

The query will be executed manually or by some other means outside of QueryDSL.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: What is `query` in your code? I'm looking for the same

Answer (score 3):

Use the setUseLiterals() method on the Configuration or on the SQLQuery object.  This has been answered here:

[How to get fully materialized query from querydsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689222/how-to-get-fully-materialized-query-from-querydsl)