# QueryDsl ComparableExpression to produce a DateTime literal using the SQL dialect

Tags: sql, datetime, querydsl, literals, dialect

I want to create a ComparableExpression that will produce a datetime literal in the generated SQL, in the dialect of the configured DBMS.
I have read this article: [How to get fully materialized query from querydsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689222/how-to-get-fully-materialized-query-from-querydsl), which produces a literal for a Long value, but I haven't seen an example that produces a date or datetime. Date literal formatting is peculiar to different DBMSs.

So in the WHERE statement I want to get this:

```
dbo.fact_table.tx_date >= {formatted date literal}
```

For the {formatted date literal}, I want to generate:

```
'19931123 00:00:00' (for MSSQL)
```

and

```
Timestamp '1993-11-23 00:00:00' (for Teradata)
```

The closest I have got is:

```
Expressions.dateTimeTemplate(Date.class, "{0}", alreadyFormattedDateString);
```

But then I have to format the date myself. I want to provide the Date object and get querydsl to do the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

My colleague has answered this for me.

We start with an OffsetDateTime but have to convert to java.util.Date because querydsl does not support java.time yet.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2016-02-01T00:00:00+13:00");
Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
Expression<Date> expr = Expressions.asDateTime(date);
```

The SQL literal produced for this Expression in MSSQL dialect is

```
{ts '2016-02-01 00:00:00'}
```

Thanks to Simon Lewis.