# Entity mapping without Hibernate (JPA)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping, entity

Need to read Java entities from database. The database choice is uncertain for now so need my code to be DB-independent. Hibernate provides enough such independency but it (as I can see) is mostly purposed for front-end. The problem is that it returns collections that are first cached on client side. My application needs reading large amount of objects for processing them in one pass. Using pure JDBC with `ResultSet` is more appropriate for this but it involves quite much boilerplate code with native SQL.

Woud like your suggestions about the solution. See it something like this: we define JPA entities, then read them from DB in an iterating manner using creteria in, for example, HQL. And the entities mustn't be collected on the client side before the iteration is started (except, probably, some buffering for performance reason).

Would also concider Java solutions not based on Hibernate/JPA.

Comment: try this http://www.jooq.org/

Comment: Thatks, @ashok-kumar-n, but the Community edition doesn't support my DB :(

Comment: what db you are using

Comment: Oracle is current and PostgreSQL is considered. Also my company opts to use free solutions.

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242388/comparing-querydsl-jooq-jequel-activejdbc-iciql-and-other-query-dsls if any comments are useful just upvote it

Comment: What do you mean with client / frontend?

Comment: @ashok-kumar-n, yes, this answer seems to show the right direction. Sorry, cannot upvote :(

Comment: already a question is there for this issue so I'm marking as duplicate

Comment: @user10815638: The money you'll spend on implementing a home grown solution to work around database dialect differences will definitely outweigh any jOOQ licenses. [Here's just a short glimpse at what jOOQ does for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44323668/521799)

Comment: @Lukas Eder, By now it's going to be at most 100 native queries. Probably easier to rewrite them all. Still under consideration though.

Comment: @user10815638, you can still use jOOQ to help you rewrite them: https://www.jooq.org/translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your use case compare the supported API for JDBC in below link 
[comparing JDBC API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7242388/comparing-querydsl-jooq-jequel-activejdbc-iciql-and-other-query-dsls)